# Sequential resource creation in terraform with count or for_each. Possible?

Tags: terraform

When I use count or for_each in my resource definition, the resources are created in parallel.
Is there a kind of workaround to make it sequential? First a resource with count.index=0 is created, then count.index=1, then count.index=2 e.t.c.

A little background...
I'm using terraform for initial Hyperledger Fabric setup. For some tasks I need to do configuration updates of the blockchain network sequentially (like approving chaincode for participating organizations). Otherwise I get (MVCC_READ_CONFLICT).
This can of course be achieved if I outsource this logic completely to some bash script but maybe...

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no terraform feature for this, but when I googled MVCC_READ_CONFLICT to see if it meant what I thought it does I found there's various discussions of your particular scenario that may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to make things work one needs to store a kind of state elsewhere. The most simple thing is to use a file:

```
resource "null_resource" "set_initial_state" {
    provisioner "local-exec" {
        interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
        command = "echo \"0\" > current_state.txt"
    }
}
```

The second resource implements a waiting loop in the beginning and state change in the end:

```
resource "null_resource" "sequential_resources" {
    count = var.x
    provisioner "local-exec" {
        interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
        command = "while [[ $(cat current_state.txt) != \"${count.index}\" ]]; do echo \"${count.index} is waiting...\";sleep 5;done"
    }

# Here you pack your sequential logic, e.g. upload of files to a service, 
# that can handle only one file at once.

    provisioner "file" {
        connection {
                type     = "ssh"
                host     = var.ip_address
                private_key = file(var.config.private_key)
                user     = var.config.admin_username
                script_path = var.provisioner_script_path
        }
        source = "${var.local_folder}/file_${count.index}.txt"
        destination = "/opt/data/file_${count.index}.txt"
    }

    provisioner "local-exec" {
        interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
        command = "echo \"${count.index+1}\" > current_state.txt"
    }

depends_on = [null_resource.set_initial_state]
}
```

In this example file_0.txt is uploaded first, then file_1.txt, then file_2.txt e.t.c. until file_x.txt

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me you are looking for a way to create dependencies on various resources so they are deployed in the sequential manner you described. One way to achieve this within the resource block is using Terraforms meta-argument `depends_on` (Link below). This meta-argument does exactly as it sounds. It allows you to define within your resource (Resource A) the name of another resource in the same module (Resource B) to finish before executing. In other words, Resource A does not start until Resource B is done. I'm not certain of the behavior when used in conjunction with loops such as `for_each` and `count`

**Note**: Terraform recommends to use this as a last resort. Review their documentation for more details.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#depends_on-explicit-resource-dependencies

Comment: Not really. I have a variable amount of similar resources that kind of depend on each other in an unparallelizable way.  E.g. Today I have 3 tomorrow 50. If I define them as different resources and use depends_on, I have to modify my code base each when I change the number. But it would work. If I use count, I just need to change one variable. But in this case all 50 resources are created at once. The logic outside terraform is like all existing resources approve adding of a new resource, but they can do it one at a time, not 3 or 50.

Comment: That makes sense. I wasn't sure how it would work when using loops. According to the documentation of depends_on, you can't use arbitrary expressions as the value so having the dependencies being defined dynamically could be an issue. I'm not aware of any other techniques to achieve what you're doing. Typically when I run into a wall like that, it generally means it's time to reconsider my approach to the problem.